# filterWhen in combination with flatMap throws exception in Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I want to filter windows where all values fulfill a certain condition and then print out the filtered fluxes:

```
Flux.just(4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .window(3)
        .filterWhen(window -> window.all(n -> n % 2 == 0))
        .flatMap(window -> window)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

However the result is not `4, 2, 6` but

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UnicastProcessor allows only a single Subscriber.
```

If I try the same but without `filterWhen` it works without exception:

```
Flux.just(4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .window(3)
        .flatMap(window -> window)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If I try it without `flatMap` no exception is thrown as well:

```
Flux.just(4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .window(3)
        .filterWhen(window -> window.all(n -> n % 2 == 0))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

However both approaches obviously don't produce the desired result. But there seems to be a **problem in the combination of `filterWhen` and `flatMap`**!

What is wrong in my first example? Where is the other subscriber?

How can I get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, as a `window` can only be subscribed to ("consumed") once. Both `flatMap` and `filterWhen` will subscribe to the window, hence your error.

What you could do instead is to use `buffer(3)` rather than `window(3)`, filter the buffers and then emit values from the buffers that passed the filter:

```
Flux.just(4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .buffer(3)
    .filter(list -> list.stream().allMatch(n -> n % 2 == 0))
    .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was absolutely not obvious to me. Is there a section in the documentation where I can learn something about this? Is it planned to add a solution for this to reactor or is it even possible with `window`?

Comment: It's not likely to be possible with window, as authorizing multiple subscriptions would open the door to unforeseen consequences like leaks. Window is already deceptively complex enough. I could add the snippet to the ref guide's faq though

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd be happy if you'd add the example to the documentation to help other developers with the same problem. Maybe some hint on the API documentation of `window` would be helpful, too.